Why are my Java text boxes only holding the last number of an imputed array? (I am using a JFrame Form for the GUI)
I have tried to get a textbox to display an array, but as far as I have tried it only shows the last number of the array
ex: array gives: 1, 24, 18, 98, 100, 78, 63, 24, 77, 46
Textbox displays: 46
Output displays:
1
24
18
98
100
78
63
24
77
46
I am wondering if there is a way to get my textbox to display the entire array?
Here is my code:
    private void btnStartProgramActionPerformed(java.awt.event.ActionEvent evt) {                                                

        int [] numbers = new int [10];
//declares an array that stores 10 integers

        for (int i=0; i<=9; i=i+1) 
/* as long as i is less than or equal to 9 increase i by one and carry out the operations in the curly brackets */

        { 

                numbers[i] = 1 + (int)(Math.random() * ((100 - 1) + 1));
// makes a random integer that is <= 1 but >=100

            lblArray.setText(String.valueOf(numbers[i]));
// prints only the last number in the array (lblArray is a jLabel)
           
            System.out.println(numbers[i]);
// prints all 10 numbers in the array
        }     
  
    }

I have tried using other text containers like text field and text area with no success. I have also tried googling my problem but I either don't understand their solutions or they don't work. I am a beginner so if I am making any big mistakes I would be open to advice.

Your comments are wrong. Each System.out.println(numbers[i]); prints just one number, the same way each lblArray.setText(String.valueOf(numbers[i])); displays just one number.

the method setText() sets the text (as suggested by its name), it does not append the text - setting most often means overwriting the previous content - the new value must be appended/concatenated to/with the previous value(s); or just convert the whole array to string  -- by the way ((100 - 1) + 1) is just a strange way to write 100

Are you talking about Swing? JavaFX? SWT? Vaadin? Add a tag and mention. An [MCVE] would help too.

You're not saving that array, so you might as well do the one-liner: lblArray.setText(ThreadLocalRandom.current().ints(10, 1, 11).mapToObj(Integer::toString).collect(Collectors.joining(", ")));

BTW,  your comment on the generated value says "makes a random integer that is <= 1 but >=100".  What it actually does is generate n so that 1 <= n <= 100.

poor man's solution: lblArray.setText(Arrays.toString(numbers));

setText() sets the value of the label. It doesn't append to the current content of it, but rather completely replaces it. If you want to keep the previous content of the label, you have to obtain it (via getText() or some other accessor method provided by the label), concatenate it and the current element of the array, and use that as the new text of the label.

Here are two ways.

the first grabs the current value from the text field and appends the next to it.  Then sets the field to that value.
the second simply creates a string of the array and sets that string.

import javax.swing.JFrame;
import javax.swing.JPanel;
import javax.swing.JTextField;
import javax.swing.SwingUtilities;

public class TryThis extends JPanel {
    JFrame f = new JFrame();
    JTextField field1 = new JTextField();
    JTextField field2 = new JTextField();

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        SwingUtilities.invokeLater(() -> new TryThis().start());
    }

    public TryThis() {
        f.add(this);
        add(field1);
        add(field2);
        f.setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
        f.pack();
        f.setLocationRelativeTo(null);
        f.setVisible(true);
    }

    @Override
    public Dimension getPreferredSize() {
        return new Dimension(200, 70);
    }

    public void start() {
        int n = 10;
        int numbers[] = new int[n];
        Random r = new Random();
        // get the previous value and append the new one
        for (int i = 0; i < n; i++) {
            numbers[i] = r.nextInt(1, 101);
            field1.setText(field1.getText() + numbers[i] + (i < n-1 ? " " : ""));
        }
        // create a string of the generated values
        String numbs = Arrays.stream(numbers).mapToObj(Integer::toString)
                .collect(Collectors.joining(" "));
        field2.setText(numbs);
    }

}

Should look something like this.

